# Unable to run git commit: Another git process seems to be running

Tags: git, commit

I keep getting this error message when trying to commit:

```
fatal: Unable to create '/[path_to_project]/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.


husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
/Users/marina.popa/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/commitizen/dist/cli/strategies/git-cz.js:102
        throw error;
        ^

Error: git exited with error code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/marina.popa/.nvm/versions/node/v4.0.0/lib/node_modules/commitizen/dist/git/commit.js:50:26)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
```

I have looked for the *index.lock* file to remove it, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: Try run this command

`rm -f ./.git/index.lock`

Comment: *"I have looked for the index.lock file to remove it, but it doesn't exist."* -- try to commit again. If the file doesn't exist it will succeed.

Comment: @RohitPoudel I tried that already

Comment: @axiac I tried like 6 times, even restarted my machine to make sure I don't have other git process running

Comment: @MarinaPopa any message display when run the command

Comment: @RohitPoudel no message

Comment: Did you try to commit from the git console directly or you're using some interface? Try directly from the console, after checking the existence of the lock file.

Comment: @Jepessen I used the `commitizen` library inside the terminal because it's configured to run other lint tasks, I have used it for the last 4 months and I doubt it has anything to do with the issue

Comment: Try git directly from the console, just to remove some entropy...

Comment: @Jepessen that's what I did

Comment: I can think about two possibilities. 1) The file is there, so try to find it and remove it is present. 2) Check if you're able to write in the `.git` folder, maybe something happened and now your user cannot write it.

Comment: @Jepessen Is not there, and I checked if the folder is writeable and it is

Comment: Try 'fg' and then press enter, you might have some background process related to git running that might be using the hook file.